# Is the set of all trees currently on earth finite, countably infinite, or uncountable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm not sure how to prove this as my professor has not shown any proofs involving real world objects, but I believe that it is finite since we know that there exists an integer k = the number of trees on earth. So we can call set B = {1, 2, 3, 4, ... ,k} and A = the set of all trees currently on earth. Then we can say $f:A \rightarrow B$ such that $f(n)=n$ is a bijection so they are in 1 to 1 correspondence so $|A| = |B|$ thus A is finite?

EDIT: Correction to my assumption: I assume since B is actually countably infinite then A is countably infinite?

Comment: Assume that every tree has a trunk at least one square millimeter in cross-section Compute the area of the earth's surface in square millimeters. That is a number greater than the number of trees on earth.

Comment: What's the difference between set $A$ and set $B$?

Comment: I don't see how this is a mathematical question.  Either there is a finite number of trees on earth or there isn't.  It seems impossible for there to be an infinite number of _anything_ "real" (i.e. not theoretical) which would seem to prove that the number of trees are finite--but this is an assumption that is impossible to be proved.

Comment: "...since we know that there exists an integer k = the number of trees on earth." You are assuming your conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Let G be the volume of the smallest atom, let EarthV be the volume of earth. Clearly the number of trees is at most EearthV/G. A tree cant be smaller than an atom and G and EarthV are both finite therefore the number of trees are finite.

Comment: volume of an atom is a little bit iffy of a concept. perharps i should have used mass. same either way